# Javascript : Font Size Increase/Decrease moves text

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, uiwebview

I have HTML pages, in which I am changing font size by using javascript syntax `"document.body.style.fontSize = 100/50/20"`

When I try to change the font size then the HTML moves text up/down according to font increase/decrease and the user is not able to persist at the same text at which the user was before changing the font size.

How can I make the user to stay at the same place as before?

Comment: it would be good to add code snippet of javascript and HTML. Also, have you checked any existing questions on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your user to `toggle` the change in font size then `javascript` is required here.

`document.body.style.fontSize` works only in one direction and i-e to apply that `size` but not reverting it back to it's original size.

```js
var font_is_large = false ;
function change_font_size( )
{
  demo_paragraph = document.getElementById( 'demo' );
  if (!font_is_large) {
  // size you want on button click //
    demo_paragraph.style.fontSize = "150%" ; 
    font_is_large = true ;
  }
  else {
   // initial font size on page load //
    demo_paragraph.style.fontSize = "100%" ;
    font_is_large = false ;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="change_font_size();">Change font size</button>

<p id="demo">lorem ipsum </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question - you want the scroll to be on the same area where it was before changing font size.

I hope this will work.

```
        //get scroll position in percentage
        var maxScroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var pos = window.scrollY;
        var percent = Math.round((pos/maxScroll)*100) ;
        
        //change font size
        document.body.style.fontSize = '15px';

        //adjust scroll to be in the same area
        var newScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var newClientScroll = (newScrollHeight * percent)/100;
        window.scrollY = newClientScroll;
```